# More than one relationship field per entry not working on tempate

Tags: templates, relationships

I have a channel set up where it's necessary to relate 2 other channels using two different relationship fields.

The relationship set up works OK within the CP.

The problem is that I don't seem to be able to output both relationship fields within my template. One or the other works fine but as soon as I put both on the template then neither work and the template tags are shown instead.

Has anyone run into this problem or have a suggestion as to how I can fix it?

Doesn't seem to work with an embed either. When using an embed and passing it the entry id I can display the related entry title but custom fields don't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got around this by using an embed an passing the entry id of the *related* entry to it like so.

```
{embed="my-embed" entry="{related-field:entry_id}"}
```